# How does init knows when to relaunch a process?

Tags: linux, init.d

I know the Zygote listens to a socket in `/dev/socket/zygote` in order to know when to fork a new process. I want to know how `init` usually does it.

I have a persistent process (not service) `X` whose `PPID=1` which corresponds to `init` and everytime I kill it `init` relaunches it. Is it normal for `init` to start processes instead of services? If so how does it usually knows the process needs to be relaunched?

Comment: Init only re-launches services started from its `*.rc` files. Init starts its child processes in foreground, so when a process is killed, being the parent process init has to handle its exit status. Its also the duty of init to reap all zombie processes.

Comment: nice! Do you know what happens if init does not handle that exit status? (For example if init exited before it). In this case is the process re-launched or don't even exits?

Comment: init can't exit when the OS is running. It has to take care of processes unless the device is fully shutdown. It's the first process launched at boot and last process killed at shutdown. Init has special protections against being killed, but if you somehow manage to kill it, it will cause kernel panic and device will reboot.

Comment: yes, but imagine a random parent process is exited before it's child then you try to kill the child, do you know what happens? (init is an exception)

Comment: Any process whose parent is killed or exits deliberately, is owned by init. This is programming related question. Read how `fork`, `exec` etc. work in C language.

Comment: oh yeah i didn't update: init simply creates an UNIX socket after the SIGTERM that connects to the system server and after a bunch of system calls it clones another process